# How to find the last time execution of the loop while(dr.Read())?

Tags: c#, asp.net

take a look at the below while loop.

```
SqlDataReader dr;

while (dr.Read())
{

Response.Write("insert into test values(N'"+dr[0]+"', N'"+dr[1]+"'),<br>");

}
```

I am just printing something with a comma at the end (before that 
). But For the last time when it gets printed, i dont want that comma. 
How to find out that this loop is executing for the last time? so that i can avoid this comma getting printed by modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's not really possible no know if you are on a last iteration of a while loop.
You could use a [loop-and-a-half](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/patterns/plopd/loops.html#loop-and-a-half), where not the last, but the first run of the loop is different, like this:

```
SqlDataReader dr = ...;

if (dr.Read())
{
  //no comma
  Response.Write("insert into test values(N'"+dr[0]+"', N'"+dr[1]+"')");
}

while (dr.Read())
{
  //put in a comma / break for the previous item
  Response.Write(",<br>insert into test values(N'"+dr[0]+"', N'"+dr[1]+"')");
}
```

However, it would be better to just use a `StringBuilder` to construct the string in memory, and then `Response.Write` it all at once, like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
while (dr.Read())
{
  //put in a comma / break for the previous item
  sb.Append("insert into test values(N'"+dr[0]+"', N'"+dr[1]+"'),<br>");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length-5,5); // remove the last ,<br>

Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. it looks good. but that comma will be printed in front of the first line right ?

Comment: No, the first line is treated in the `if`, not in the `while`. The `while` runs from the second to the last line. The downside to this approach is that some (almost same) code is written twice, so it's harder to debug and maintain.

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine.  And please check with my answer. i hope its a bit simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I would restructure it slightly.  Before your reader, instantiate a false Boolean.  After your first read set it to true.  Then, in your read code, add if true, add the comma and break to the previous line.  Then you don't have to worry about whether or not it is the last line, because there will be no next line to add the comma and break.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you exactly need but based on:

> But For the last time when it gets printed, i dont want that comma.

You can use [string.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) after exiting the loop.

```
string str = yourstring.TrimEnd(',');
```

If your string has comma at the end, it will remove it and if it doesn't it will leave the string as it is.

EDIT: Missed the Respose.Write part.

You can Build a string in the while loop and then use `string.TrimEnd` and later use `Response.Write` with the new string.

Comment: `Response.Write` already did whatever it does to the string, it's too late to trim it after.

Comment: @SWeko, You are right. I missed it. I think in that case, the OP can build the string in while loop and then later call `Response.Write` on  the trimmed string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) method for removing last comma.

> Removes all trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in
>   an array from the current String object

```
str.TrimEnd(',');
```

You should follow an instruction similar to these;

```
string str = null;
while (dr.Read())
{

str += "insert into test values(N'"+dr[0]+"', N'"+dr[1]+"'),<br>";

}

str = str.TrimEnd(',');
Response.Write(str);
```

Comment: Gonul okay. but i need to trim it only at the last iteration. is there any way to find it?

Comment: Using a `+=` on a string in a loop is [terrible for performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182272%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @SWeko Yes of course, StringBuilder looks better choice on a string in a loop but in this case I don't think so it could be big problem..

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need a variable!

```
        bool first=true;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (first) first = false;
            else Response.Write(",<br>");
            Response.Write("insert into test values(N'" + dr[0] + "', N'" + dr[1] + "')");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this... it will help you..

```
SqlDataReader dr;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Load(dr);

int _RowCount = dt.Rows.Count;

int inc = 0 ; 


while (dr.Read())
{

inc = inc + 1;

if(inc==_RowCount)

//Without Comma

else

//With Comma

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataReader dr;

while (dr.Read())
{

Response.Write("insert into test values(N'"+dr[0]+"', N'"+dr[1]+"'),<br>");

}
```

Instead of using Respose.Write, put the string in a variable like this

```
while (dr.Read())
    {

   string yourstring =  "insert into test values(N'"+dr[0]+"', N'"+dr[1]+"'),<br>";

    }
```

and After the loop you can use

```
string str = yourstring.Substring(0, yourstring.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = 0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            Response.Write(",<br>");
        }
        Response.Write("insert into test values(N'" + dr[0] + "', N'" + dr[1] + "')");
        i++;
    }
```

**it solved my problem.** And @SWeko's solution also worked fine. 
Thank you so much guys for the help.